# Spring Data Rest - unable to update nested object with PUT or PATCH

Tags: spring-data-jpa, many-to-many, spring-data-rest

I have Many-To-Many relation between Attribute and AttributeGroup. AttributeGroup contains many attributes and those attributes can be a children of more than one AttributeGroup.
Though Attribute is child of AttributeGroup, it is always created in its own repository, i.e., it is expected to have the Attribute created before AttributeGroup and when the child relationship is added during the creation of AttributeGroup.
Using attribute repo, I could do all the CRUD operations and using attributeGroup repo, successfully process the CRUD operations. During AttributeGroup creation, the relationship to Attribute also work as expected.
Next, if I want to change the relation, i.e., drop an existing Attribute and/or add another another attribute, it does not work.
I read that for updating the nested object PATCH works, but PATCH throws an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field Attribute.id to AttributeGroup
```

Please let me know what is wrong with this implementation.

**AttributeGroup.java**

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AttributeGroup implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8264102706248686536L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    String name;
    String displayName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1)
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    List<Attribute> attributes;
}
```

**Attribute.java**

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Attribute implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8806808817130076030L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    String name;

    String value;

    AttributeType attributeType;

    ArrayList<String> values;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "attributes")
    @ToString.Exclude
    List<AttributeGroup> attributeGroups;
}
```

**AttributeTye.java**

```
public enum AttributeType {
    TEXT("Text Only");

    private final String attributeType;

    AttributeType(String productType) {
        this.attributeType = productType;
    }
}
```

Comment: The patch request that I am using is 
`curl --location --request PATCH 'http://localhost:8080/attributeGroups/1' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--data-raw '{
  "attributes": [
    "http://localhost:8080/attributes/1",
    "http://localhost:8080/attributes/2",
    "http://localhost:8080/attributes/3"
  ]
}'`

Answer (score 0):

In `bidirectinoal` relationships, you need to syncronize both sides of arelationship to be able to delete an entity.

`AttributeGroup` is the owner of the relationship. So, it must have a method like below in it:

```
public void removeAttribute(Attribute attribute){
    if(attributes.contains(attribute)){
        attributes.remove(attribute);
        attribute.getAttributeGroups().remove(this);
    }
}
```

Also, in `Attribute` class you should have:

```
@PreRemove
void removeAttributeFromAttributeGroups(){
        for (AttributeGroup attributeGroup : attributesGroups) {
            attributeGroup.removeAttribute(this);
        }
}
```

The same procedure is applied to `Add` operation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried bi-directional with your code and with this [link](https://notesonjava.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/managing-the-bidirectional-relationship/) but I could maintain the integrity of data with Update.

Comment: @Senthil As your provided link (however its for maintaining @OneToMany relationship) suggests, my answer should solve your problem. If not, please provide a bit more of your code including `service` methods where you probably call The `addAttribute` and `deleteAttribute` methods

Comment: Thanks again Morteza. I am using spring-data-rest and do not have controller/custom controller or service classes. There are only entities and their corresponding repositories. I am giving a second try and update. 
The codes are now with too many log statements for debugging and if did not work, I will clean up and put is here.